# Python Selenium: Still Struggling with grasping how Profiles and Options work: Trying to disable The Firefox popup Password Manager

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, profile

I am very new to Python and Selenium. I am working on a script that I can run to access a web site and book a session. What is still killing me is the Firefox pop up Password Manager. How do I dismiss the password manager pop up, or stop it from popping up at all?

If I manually dismiss the Password Manager, the script executes just fine, working as as expected.

This is the image: [image]

However, if I do not manually dismiss it, the script does not dismiss it either, and the bulk of the HTML of the last page does not display, and I get these errors. It seems to confirm that the find_element_by-xpath command can't find the element, which is logical if the HTML code is unavailable.

return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //ul/li[@data-index='3']

After some research, I added a section with the key lines of:

```
profile.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile
```

This seems to be syntactically correct, as I am getting no errors for those lines of code, but the
script has the same flaw whether I use those lines or not (comment them out). Any idea what is wrong?

The entire code is:

```
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#Using Firefox to access the Web
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

profile.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
driver.maximize_window()

# Open the website
driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com/book-something.html#no-redirect')

# click on the sign in tab to get Login Window
driver.find_element_by_class_name('c-header__login-text').click()

# finding the Login Window User ID Box and sending the Login ID
User_ID = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-login-email')
User_ID.send_keys('xxxx')

#Finding the Login Window Password Box and sending the Password
Password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-login-password')
Password.send_keys('yyyy')

#Finding the Login Window Log-In Button and Clicking on it
driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-login-submit').click()

#Pause a few seconds until the My Account Button appears
time.sleep(5)

#Find the unordered list that contains the 4th day (data-index 3) and then click on the element that is the 4th day
#Seven_Days = driver.find_element_by_xpath('c-schedule-calendar__unordered-list-toggle')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[@data-index='3']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set profile preferences to FALSE.

PYTHON:

profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)

Comment: Is that not Javascript? When I added those 2 lines, removed the semi-colon's, I got this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/OpenSite5.py", line 11, in <module>
    profile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false)
AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'setPreference'

Comment: Try now, and let me know did it help you. Use same code as in question , but different prefeerence and value.

Comment: Sorry, still getting the popup. This is the code, including lines commented out:```profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

#profile.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
#profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.maximize_window()

Comment: I added the popup image to the main body of the question. Thanks.